# Is there an elegant way to show a progress bar during the computation of a grouped data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, progress-bar, grouping

I am applying a complex function to a grouped data.frame. For simplicity reasons, here, this function will be treated as the colSums function. Let's assume we have the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A=runif(600000,0,1),
                 B=rep(c("group1", "group2","group3","group4","group5","group6"), 100000))
```

Further I want to execute a dplyr chain:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(.data$B) %>%
    summarize(colSums(across()))
```

During this calculation, I'd like to have a Progress bar showing the remaining time.
For example:

[=========================>] 100%

I know there are solutions in dplyr, but as far as I know they are superseded. Thus, I want to use the package Progress. This Progress bar is based on a tick update during a for loop. I am wondering, if this is possible for this dplyr chain. So far, I couldnt come up with a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Not a direct answer to the specific question, but I will often do things like this using `furrr`. This is a version of `purrr` which enables fairly easy parallel computing, and has a built in progress bar. the vignettes are pretty helpful. You'd need to split the data on your own, but then you can use the `future_map()` functions from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the progress package.  You have to initialize the progress bar and tell it the number of groups/ticks.  Then in your custom computation, you increment the bar.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(progress)

df <- data.frame(A=runif(600000,0,1),
                 B=rep(c("group1", "group2","group3","group4","group5","group6"), 100000)) %>% 
    group_by(B)

my_slow_function <- function(col){
    pb$tick()
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    sum(col)
}

num_ticks <- n_groups(df)
pb <- progress_bar$new(format = "[:bar] :current/:total (:percent) elapsed :elapsed eta :eta",
                       total = num_ticks)


df %>% 
    summarize(output = my_slow_function(A))
```